# Facebook OpenGraph with Yii Framework - Authentication Issue

Tags: php, facebook, yii, infinite-loop, access-token

I am having an issue with the php Facebook sdk.
I have read many posts talking about the same kind of issues (Access token invalid, redirect loop etc...) but none could help.

Briefly, how my project is designed:

It is a Facebook application that is meant to run only with a user logged in Facebook.
Using the Yii Framework, I have created a Filter that is called every time a page is loaded, to ensure that the content is visible only by Facebook logged on users.
It should behave exactly like the application BranchOut on Facebook.

My issue, and how to reproduce it:

- I logon to my application using the typical login process from Facebook (OAuth, access token)
- I logout manually on the Facebook page, and then try to do a new action on my application
- The filter checks if I am logged on Facebook, and because I am not, it redirects me to the Facebook login page.
- After I login to Facebook again, I get the typical infinite loop between Facebook and my application's filter.

Here is the code of my filter:

```
$fb_logged = false;
try
{
    $user = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();
    $me = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me');
    $fb_id = $me['id'];
    $fb_logged = true;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $fb_logged = false;
}

if($fb_logged)
{
    print_r($fb_id. ' has logged');
    /* Check if user exists on MyApp 
     ... */
}
// If user NOT logged on FB, send him to the FB login page
else
{
    $loginUrl = Yii::app()->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'redirect_uri' => Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrl() // I have tried many things here.
        ));
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

What is exactly happening is that after login on FB, the Filter is called again, because a request to the same URL is made. And at that point, the a call the api('/me') generates an exception, because it cannot find any valid access token, and starts looping on it.

I can add that my configuration is good (or seems to be), I have checked all my urls, domain name according to Facebook's app settings.
I have also tried many things like redirecting to a new specific URL, but anyway I need to use the filter as well because I want to make sure this is still the same user (or act consequently if the user has changed).

The only thing that works is to redirect the user to a page that has no Filter (no call to api("/me") is done). And then, clicking by hand to a new link in the application, and there the access token is found. And this is not the behavior I want.

I really hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found what the issue is so far. I'm experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

After your new login attempt, you should get a new code in the URL that is redirect to. So look for that code parameter, and if it’s there, exchange it for a new access token.

Comment: Do you know a way to do that with the SDK? Normally the method getUser() is supposed to do all this, but no way, with the getUser(), I get the FB id even if I am logged out... I have also tried to clean up session/cookie, to do a call to getUser(), to be sure the new access_token will be requested, but noway! The call to api('/me') just after still tells me that there is no active token.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [yiiauth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiauth/) extension as well. It was posted just today, and with it you can log in with 29 different providers: Facebook, OpenID, Google, Twitter, Yahoo etc.

It uses the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html) library and AFAICT it makes authentication very easy.

Comment: Thanks Ors. What I want to do is an Authentication implicit. I don't want people to click on a login button or something. I just want them to be logged in my app automatically if they are logged in FB. I don't think this is possible with yiiauth.